# Make HSQLDB Compatibility with DB2

Tags: db2, hsqldb

HSQL-2.3.2 is using as in-memory to test the application which is integrated DB2.

So I am setting sql.syntax_db2=true in url as below in order to provide DB2 compatibility

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:{path};shutdown=true;sql.syntax_db2=true
```

when above url using "SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX DB2 FALSE" statement created in generated script file,but when i am passing db2,ora syntax true as below

```
jdbc:hsqldb:file:{path};shutdown=true;sql.syntax_db2=true;sql.syntax_ora=true
```

then both statements `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX DB2 TRUE` and `SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE` are created and db2 syntax is not executing  and below exception firing

nested exception is `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: IGNORE`

So please share where needs to make change in order to make DB2 compatibility?

Thanks,
Durgesh

Comment: `syntax_db2=true` ***and*** `syntax_ora=true` doesn't make sense (you can't be compatible to DB and Oracle at the same time). Besides: testing a DB centric application against a different DBMS isn't really useful.

Comment: The only DBMS that is truly compatible with DB2 is DB2.

Comment: My intention is not set compatibility with both DBy's,is only checking can we make statement as TRUE.My requirement is make compatibility with DB2,but not able to make it(second scenario able to make).I agree testing with different DBMS is not a good,but i have a exceptional case.I have to do it

Comment: I need to use HSQL, whatever the extent it provides compatibility with DB2

Comment: Please report the SQL statement that is causing the exception. It may not be supported by HSQLDB even in DB2 compatibility mode.